# Apply ng-class to parent element if any checkbox is clicked using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a parent list with a dropdown of checkboxes that you can see if you click on the list. What I want to do is give the parent list class "active" if any of the checkboxes are checked. What's happening now is that I have multiple lists so if the checkbox is checked all lists will get that class when I only want the list the checkboxes are in to get the "active" class. How can I refactor this so only the "active" class is given to the parent list, not all lists?

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="type in filterTypes">
    <li ng-repeat="filter in type.filters" ng-class="{active:checked}">{{filter.value | uppercase}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
                <label>
                    //if any checkbox is checked, the active class should be given to the parentd list at the way top.
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
                    {{option}}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Directive:**

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/all-filters.html',
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        scope.filterTypes = dummyData.filters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `checked` to `filter.checked` in the model and class directives.

Comment: @JamesBuck this makes all checkboxes checked (true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the checked property to each option by changing the model to `ng-model="option.checked"`

Then on the li element change the `ng-class` directive to call a function to check if any option within the filter is checked

```
$scope.isAnyChecked = function(filter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filter.options.length; i++) {
        if (filter.options[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then apply the active class if it returns true

```
ng-class="isAnyChecked(filter) ? 'active' : ''"
```

Comment: how does it check if the filter is checked if the filters do not have the property "checked" already...I'm getting this error: Cannot create property 'checked' on string 'filter1'

Comment: @user5694093 You will have to change `options` to be an array of objects instead of an array of strings. If that is not possible, then you'll have to create a new property on the filter than can store the model value of each checkbox and adjust the `isAnyChecked` function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I made the options into objects. Works nicely now. Would you say this is the most appropriate angular way?

Comment: @user5694093 Yes, usually when you use ng-repeat it's recommended to use objects instead of primitives. See [here](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input ng-model='checked' ng-change='filter.checked=checked'/>
```

Comment: this won't work because as soon as I click another checkbox the "checked" value will turn false, making the class "active" disappear. I want to keep the class "active" as long as one of the boxes are checked.